# set-cookie is set in response header but it is not showing in Application->Cookies

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome, cookies, csrf, netlify

The front end spa is hosted in netlify and backend in heroku. And sending the cookies in response header as shown in the image. But it is not set in the chrome devtools Application or can't be accessed through document.cookie from console.
[image]

Comment: Try using `withCredentials: true` in the request.

Comment: withCredentials:true will only attach cookies to your request while sending to server.. The reason will for this would be either CORS or something else..

Comment: Yes, this is cors issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long search I found that you cannot set cookie for cross origin.
I am using Vue and Django Rest Framework.

You can use subdomains and set cookie with samesite 'none', secure and set domain to '.example.com'.

Answer (score 0):

When using Vue, you can set cross origin cookies by setting up a proxy in the Vue app.

This works in development where you can edit vue.config.js and add the following:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'http://localhost:3000'
  }
}
```

Another syntax if you want to be more specific would be:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '^/api': {
        target: '<url>',
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here you can prepend your proxy url to any req from the front end with /api prepended to it. The proxy will allow cookies to be sent to your frontend while in development.

The Vue proxy [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy) goes over it in a bit more detail.

---

For React users, it is a bit different as you need to add the proxy in the React App package.json like this:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3000"
```

Here is the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) for React proxies