# Set-cookie in response-header is not set in Chrome

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cookies

I am creating an application using Vue.js with Vite for client-side and express.js for the server-side on docker. The server side sends the cookie as a response to Axios request front client, and I can see Set-cookie in the response-header. However, this cookie is not set to the browser. I opened the Application tab and checked the cookie, but nothing was there.

I checked the reason why this is happening, and I suspect that the domain of the serer side is localhost. Can anyone tell me how to change the domain NAME from localhost to anything else with which cookie is set in browser?
If localhost is not the reason for it, can anyone think of the reason why this happened?

I found this answer, but I'm not sure only with this explanation. Also, withcredential: true caused cors issue.

[set-cookie is set in response header but it is not showing in Application->Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66197465/set-cookie-is-set-in-response-header-but-it-is-not-showing-in-application-cooki)

I appreciate a more comprehensive explanation if anyone can do so.
Thank you.

Comment: `Can anyone tell me how to change the domain NAME from localhost to anything else with which cookie is set in browser?` - you can't

Comment: Are your server and client running on the same port of localhost? or different?
Can you give us the both URLs here?

Comment: Client side URL is : http://localhost:15173/login, Serverside URL is: http://localhost:3000/login. They are running on different containers on Docker.