# Set-Cookie in header and also in response cookies under dev tools, but Application > Cookies is empty and has no cookie?

Tags: express, cookies, axios

I'm trying to set a cookie for my Vue app using express and axios.

Here is my request using axios:

```
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/login/', loginDetails, {
        withCredentials: true, 
        credentials: 'include'
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log('login response: ', response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error.message)
        console.error(error.response.status)
    });
```

It is handled by express where I use res.cookie() like so:

```
// Set Status
res.status(200)
            
// Set User Cookie
res.cookie("token", token, { httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'none', secure: true, maxAge: 86400 })

// Send the JWT to the client
res.send({
    data: user,
    token: token,
    message: "Logged in successfully!"
})
```

After sending the request, I can see the cookie in the response cookies dev tools:
[image: Response Cookies in Dev Tools]

I also see Set-Cookie in the response headers:
[image]

However, when I check my Application > Storage > Cookies in dev tools it is empty

I've tried setting withCredentials = true on both my client side request and server side response but it doesn't seem to work.

I also played around with my cors setting based on other similar questions but to no avail.

I've also read here:
[set-cookie is set in response header but it is not showing in Application->Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66197465/set-cookie-is-set-in-response-header-but-it-is-not-showing-in-application-cooki)
that I need to use a subdomain to set the cookie but I do not quite understand the solution or how to implement it

Comment: A cookie with the `Secure` attribute will only be set over an HTTPS connection. Yours is HTTP, however.

Comment: I tried to remove the secure attribute from the res.cookie() options but I get the following error with Set-Cookie:
Mark cross-site cookies as Secure to allow setting them in cross-site contexts

Comment: `SameSite = none` requires `Secure` to be set. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite#none

Comment: So apparently cookies are not allowed to be sent to the client from the server if they both are on different ports. My client is running on 8080 and my server is 3000. Cookies can only be sent and set if they are on the same server. I read that you can proxy the requests from the front end like so: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy. However, I wasn't able to get this to work and it also doesn't explain how you would solve this issue in production.

Comment: The problem in your case is only the missing HTTPS connection. In production (outside localhost), you might also encounter third-party cookie problems, but that depends on the domain names of your hosting services.

Comment: I have my backend on port 3000 setup as https://localhost:3000 with a self signed certificate so it is secure and working. I can get the cookie in postman when I make a request, but it just doesn't show up in the frontend app running on http://localhost:8080. Does the frontend also need to be https?

Comment: If the frontend is on http, the secure cookie is not set "due to user preferences" (meaning third-party cookie settings).